# iphone app promoting picture

Tags: iphone, screenshot, app-store-connect, promoting

where can I create pictures like [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-SBwO4K2eMvk/T-xxWfvDikI/AAAAAAAABKc/He7oqoIZr4A/s1600/iphone_not_stacked.png) of my app? is there any online tool or any software?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

1. http://mockuphone.com/
2. https://placeit.net/

I use,

[Promotee](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/promotee/id578071639?mt=12) - A mac app

Answer (score 0):

You can take screenshots of simulator, and add them to an iPhone image using Preview (built-in in mac)

Comment: I've already thought of this idea but I'd like to see there also that shine across the screen.